# PLSQL Creating a package that calls on procedures and functions from other scheme

Tags: function, plsql, package, procedure

I'm trying to create a package (user_mgt) in SCHEME1 where it calls forth on a procedure (change_pwd) and a function (check_password) from SCHEME2. I'm not exactly sure on how to correctly define the parameters and variables that exist within the procedure and function. Do I need to somehow connect those two schemes? Would love some advice!

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE user_mgmt AS

    PROCEDURE CHANGE_PWD (P_USERNAME IN USERS.USERNAME %TYPE,                                         
                                    P_OLD_PW   USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE,                                     
                                    P_NEW_PW IN USERS.PASSWORD %TYPE, 
                                    P_SUCCES OUT BOOLEAN );

    FUNCTION check_password 
(P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2, 
P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN BOOLEAN IS 
V_CHECK NUMBER(1); 

end user_mgmt;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY user_mgmt AS

PROCEDURE CHANGE_PWD (P_USERNAME IN USERS.USERNAME %TYPE,                                         
                                    P_OLD_PW  IN USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE,                                     
                                    P_NEW_PW IN USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE, 
                                    P_SUCCES OUT BOOLEAN ) IS
 VC_OLD_PW   USERS.PASSWORD%TYPE;

 BEGIN

    SELECT U.PASSWORD 
      INTO VC_OLD_PW 
      FROM USERS U
     WHERE U.USERNAME = p_username;


   IF VC_OLD_PW = P_OLD_PW THEN
      UPDATE USERS
         SET PASSWORD = p_new_pw
       WHERE USERS.USERNAME = p_username;
       COMMIT;

      P_SUCCES   := TRUE;
   ELSE 

      P_SUCCES  := FALSE;

   END IF;

EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN    
    P_SUCCES  := FALSE;   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error in procedure CHANGE_PWD '||SQLERRM);
END CHANGE_PWD;


FUNCTION check_password     (P_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2, 
                            P_PASSWORD IN VARCHAR2) 
                            RETURN BOOLEAN IS 
V_CHECK NUMBER(1); 

    BEGIN 

        SELECT 1 INTO V_CHECK
        FROM USERS
        WHERE UPPER(P_USERNAME) = UPPER(USERS.USERNAME) 
        AND (P_PASSWORD) = (USERS.PASSWORD); 

RETURN TRUE; 

        EXCEPTION 
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN return false; 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN return false; 
        End check_password;


END user_mgmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SCHEME2` can grant `SCHEME1` permission to run the stored procedure (a user and a schema are pretty much synonymous in Oracle).
So in your case, you should log in to SCHEMA2 and give appropriate permissions using `GRANT` statement:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ... TO a SCHEME1
```

User `SCHEME1` would then call the procedure using `SCHEME2.package_name.procedure_name`

Moreover, on `SCHEME1` you can create a synonym in order to avoid prefixing with username each time

```
CREATE SYNONYM <synonym_name> FOR SCHEME2.<procedure_name>;
```